# Receiving gibberish when reading from a TLS TCP socket

Tags: c, http, ssl, https, server

I have a C program (simple web server) that listens to port 8080 for incoming HTTP requests. It works great if I make a simple `http://` request, I can see the request headers. But when I make a `https://` SSL/TLS request then I am seeing some gibberish `?????`

Instead, I expect to see the SSL/TLS client-hello handshake message.

http://localhost:8080 request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
```

https://localhost:8080 request:

```
???? ???? ??
```

Why am I not seeing the TLS client-hello initializing the handshake message? It is not encrypted yet (at least shouldn't be at this point)

Here is my C server, I am reading from the socket using `read( new_socket , buffer, 30000)`

```
// Server side C program to demonstrate HTTP Server programming
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 8080
int main(void)
{
    int server_fd, new_socket; long valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);

    char *hello = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/plain\nContent-Length: 12\n\nHello world!";

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );

    memset(address.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof address.sin_zero);


    bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n+++++++ Waiting for new connection ++++++++\n\n");
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {
            perror("In accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        char buffer[30000] = {0};
        valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 30000);
        printf("%s\n",buffer );
        write(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello));
        printf("------------------Hello message sent-------------------");
        close(new_socket);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TLS is a binary protocol, not text like HTTP.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, that makes sense. Is there a way I can decode/convert that binary to text?

Comment: Use a library like OpenSSL.

Comment: If you want to roll your own, read the protocol specification.

Comment: @Barmar yes that was the idea, to do it without using a library but all by myself.

Comment: Thanks, found this to be very helpful - https://tls.ulfheim.net/

Comment: Very nice find, good luck with this.

Comment: @Liga Be vary of which TLS version server is using.

Comment: Moreover if you want to use TLS with as much ease as TCP. Use this.https://github.com/markoneill/ssa

Comment: @Barmar is it possible to print out the actual binary in C?

Comment: Sure, use a loop that prints each byte.

Comment: @Barmar Im a newbie, how could I print each byte?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < valread; i++) { printf("%x ", buffer[i]); }`

Comment: BTW, you should use `unsigned char` for the buffer.

Comment: @Barmar thank you very much for all the help! I with I could mark it as accepted answer!

Comment: It's not the answer to the question.

Comment: You could also install a packet sniffer on your localhost machine. It will recognize TLS protocol showing you the meaning of each header field (until the encryption starts). I usually use Wireshark.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  regarding: `bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))`  it is missing the `required` trailing semicolon `;`

Comment: regarding: `while(1)`   Just before this statement should be a call to `listen()`

Comment: regarding: `valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 30000);
        printf("%s\n",buffer );`  The function: `read()` does not NUL terminate the buffer, so 1)  check for an error indication (the value in `valread` < 0 and handle that error.  2) check the value in `valread` ==0 to indicate the other end of the connection closed.  3)  since the data will be binary rather than ascii, there is no guarantee that the data does not contain a NUL byte Suggest using `write( 1, buffer, valbyte );` to display the data

Comment: regarding: `char *hello = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/plain\nContent-Length: 12\n\nHello world!`  the http protocol uses `\r`, NOT `\n` and the above is missing the trailing `\r`

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char const *argv[])`  the posted code does not use the parameters: `argc` nor `argv[]`.  To avoid two of the warning messages from the compiler, about unused parameters, strongly suggest using the other valid signature for `main()`  I.E. `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `int addrlen = sizeof(address);`  The functiion: `accept()` is expecting the last parameter to be of type `socklen_t` Therefore, suggest: `socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(address);`  especially since the `sizeof` operator returns a `size_t` not an `int`